# Is the binary matrix of transaction database low-rank in the problem of association rules mining?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata

In the problem of association rules mining, the transaction database with $N$ transactions and $M$ items can be represented by a binary matrix $D$ with dimension $N \times M$. My questions are:

1. Is $D$ low-rank or approximately low-rank? Equivalently, are there only few large singular values dominate the overall singular values of $D$?
2. Intuitively, only few items on average are contained in each transaction because a customer generally buy only few items. However, is that true?

It will be much appreciated if someone familiar this field could answer my questions or even only provide any clues.